# Showing a messagebox error

Tags: c#, google-maps, monodevelop, messagebox, itemizedoverlay

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and am wanting to implement a messagebox.

I am currently trying this code out in the MapsAndLocationDemo.

Here is my code:

```
    public void createMessageBox (string stringQuestion)
    {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
        builder.SetTitle ("Test");
        builder.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        builder.SetMessage (stringQuestion);

        builder.SetPositiveButton ("Yes", (sender, e) => { 
            Toast.MakeText (this, "You clicked positive button", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        });

        builder.SetNegativeButton ("No", (sender, e) => { 
            Toast.MakeText (this, "You clicked negative button", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        });

        builder.SetNeutralButton ("Maybe", (sender, e) => { 
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You clicked neutral button", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        });

        var dialog = builder.Create ();
        dialog.Show ();
    }
```

This code works fine when called from the main 'OnCreate' function. However, I am wanting to call this code from an 'Overlay' that is of base 'ItemizedOverlay'.

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'MapsAndLocationDemo.MapWithOverlayActivity' via nested type 'MapsAndLocationDemo.MapWithOverlayActivity.MapItemizedOverlay'

How can I please get this to work? Or is there a better way to display a messagebox?

Thanks

Comment: You posted the wrong code.  A function named "createMessageBox" ought to be static.

Answer (score 1):

All that needed to be done was to make the function static.